# SQL Server Join Query returns redundant rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, left-join

I have two table

```
tblMaster          tblTrans
ID  Desc           ID  IDMaster  Qty     Garage
==  ======         ==  ========= =====   =====
1   Type1          1   1         1       1
2   Type2          2   2         2       1
                   3   1         3       2
                   4   2         2       2
                   5   1         2       3
                   6   2         4       3
```

And i want this output when i join them :

```
ID Desc  Garage1Qty  Garagae2Qty Garage3Qty  Garage4Qty
== ====  =========== =========== =========== ==========
1  Type1 1           3           2           null
2  Type2 2           2           4           null
```

Note that the "Garage" value is something that could be added in the future. So how do i achieve that? Tried this one:

```
SELECT M.*, Garage1Qty.*, Garage2Qty.* FROM tblMaster M
LEFT JOIN (  SELECT a.Id, b.Qty FROM tblMaster a JOIN tblTrans b on a.Id =b.Id WHERE Garage = 1 ) as Garage1Qty on Garage1Qty.Id = M.Id )
LEFT JOIN (  SELECT a.Id, b.Qty FROM tblMaster a JOIN tblTrans b on a.Id =b.Id WHERE Garage = 2 ) as Garage2Qty on Garage2Qty.Id = M.Id )
```

but it always returns something like:

```
ID Desc  Garage1Qty  Garage2Qty  Garage3Qty  Garage4Qty
== ====  =========== =========== =========== ==========
1  Type1 1           null        null         null
1  Type1 null        3           null         null
1  Type1 null        null        2            null
2  Type2 2           null        null         null
2  Type2 null        2           null         null
2  Type2 null        null        4            null
```

Comment: please, do create a sql fiddle with test/sample data. It will be helpful for you to get your answer quicker.

Comment: Is the number of Garages to show always 4?

Comment: A simple `PIVOT` gets most of the way to the result you're looking for. But if the number of garages varies then you'll have to embrace dynamic SQL - a single SQL query always produces a result set with the same "shape" - the *number* of columns, their names and types are fixed. So if you want a varying number of columns, you have to construct the whole query on the fly. What's *consuming* this result set? Does it not have better pivotting functionality available?

Comment: @PaulKaram Edited my question, pls check

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Yes, i could use dynamic query. The problem is that the garage is ALSO dynamic smh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you could use `subquery`

```
select ID, Desc,
       (select sum(Qty) from tblTrans where IDMaster = m.ID and Garage = 1) as Garage1Qty, 
       (select sum(Qty) from tblTrans where IDMaster = m.ID and Garage = 2) as Garage2Qty,
       (select sum(Qty) from tblTrans where IDMaster = m.ID and Garage = 3) as Garage3Qty,
       (select sum(Qty) from tblTrans where IDMaster = m.ID and Garage = 4) as Garage4Qty
from tblMaster m;
```

In other way, you could also do that via conditional aggregation

```
select m.ID, m.Desc,
       sum(case when t.Garage = 1 then t.Qty else 0 end) as Garage1Qty,
       ...
       sum(case when t.Garage = 4 then t.Qty else 0 end) as Garage4Qty
from tblMaster m left join tblTrans t
                 on t.IDMaster = m.ID
group by m.ID, m.Desc;
```

Comment: I'll try this solution

Comment: This works just fine for me. However, any idea how to make it dynamic (in this case garage) ? Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @Lmao.. You should look into `pivot` with dynamic approach. There are lots of sample examples are available on `SO` . So, go ahead and ask the question with your `pivot` effort if you are getting stuck.